# Is it possible to solve a fractional knapsack including negative values using greedy algorithm?

Tags: greedy

I have a problem which I think can be converted to a variant of 
[fractional knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_knapsack_problem) problem.

The objective function is in the form of:

$\sum_{i} x_iv_i$

However, my problem differs in that it allows $v_i$ s and $x_i$ to be negative.

I want to prove that this problem can be solved using the greedy algorithm (explained in the link).

I have tested this for many test cases and greedy algorithm seems to solve it, but I want a definite 
proof that greedy algorithm is still applicable given the extra constraint.

Comment: Provide some code. And prepare to argue that this is not your homework.

Comment: It is a LP problem. I code it in java using Gurobi. I have tested the greedy algorithm by hand for many cases and compare the result with the output of my code.

Answer (score 1):

In the fractional knapsack problem, you find the Value/Weight of every item that you may put in the knapsack, and sort these items from the best V/W ratio to the worst. You then start with the best ratio, and fill the knapsack is either full or you run out. If you run out, you then head to the next item in the list and fill the knapsack with it. This pattern continues until the knapsack is full. It is greedy, because once we sort this list we know that we can confidently add the items fractionally in this order and that we will end with the greatest potential value in the bag.

By allowing the values and "weights" to be negative, as in this problem, however, the algorithm is no longer greedy. It is ruined by the fact that an item could have a negative "weight" and negative value, resulting in a positive V/W ratio. For example, take the following list of items:

1. V=-1, W=-1  -> V/W = 1.0
2. V=.9, W=1  -> V/W = 0.9
3. V=.8, W=1  -> V/W = 0.8

Following the greedy algorithm, we would want to add as much of item 1 as exists, because it has the best V/W ratio. However, adding item 1 really hurts us in the long run, because we are losing more value per weight then we can add later on. For example, let's assume the |W|=10 for each, and the max weight of the knapsack is 10. By adding all of 1, we will have a weight of -10 and a value of -10. Then we add all of 2, which results in a weight of 0 and a value of -1. Then we add all of 3, which results in a weight of 10 and a value of 7.

If instead of this, we just added all of item 2 from the start, we would have a weight of 10 and a value of 9. Therefore by contradiction, if weight and value can be negative, the algorithm is NOT a greedy algorithm.